# Watermelon Disease Identification

Tags: diseases, watermelon

[image: Watermelon fruit with discolouration]

[image: Watermelon leaves with brown markings]

[image: Closeupof leaves]

I've planted this watermelon 50 days ago, I'm in Zone 8 in Dallas, TX. I'm wondering what the disease that has afflicted the leaves is, and if I should harvest the fruit now and if it's still edible.